# What are some verses about(against) materialism in upanishad and vedas?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

Hinduism is against materialistic people and materialism, so what are some verses from Upanishads and vedas the condemns it.

Comment: Hinduism is not against Materialism. It's against , being perpetually cozy and comfortable in that mithyā (false) pond of sāṃsārika māyā. Materialism is what keeps the world going on, so that new jīvas are born as per their previous births saṃskāras. However, being eternally struck in that 'pond', and **not realizing** our true nature of eternal atman (sat-chitt-ānanda): this is what is admonished in hinduism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the verses against materialistic Desires,wealth and pleasure in Upanishads.

> The good is one thing; the pleasant, another. Both  of these, serving
> different needs, bind a man. It goes well with  him who, of the two,
> takes the good; **but he who chooses the  pleasant misses the end**. O
> Nachiketa, after pondering well the **pleasures that are or  seem to
> he delightful, you have renounced them all**. You have
> **not taken the road abounding in wealth, where many men sink**.I regard you, O  Nachiketa, to be one who desires Knowledge; for even
> many
> **pleasures could not tempt you away.**        (Katha Up 1.2.1-4)
>
> The way to the future does not shine for the ignorant man who
> blunders, rendered, **blind by folly caused by wealth; thinking thus
> ‘this world is and none other,**’ be gets into my power(rebirth/death)
> again and again.(Katha Up 1.2.6)
>
> **The ignorant pursue external objects of desire**; they get into the meshes of widespread death: but the intelligent, knowing sure
> immortality, do not covet the uncertain things here.(Katha Up 2.1.2)
>
> When **all desires clinging to the heart of one fall off**, **then the
> mortal becomes immortal** and here attains Brahman.(Katha Up 2.3.14)
>
> That which transcends hunger and thirst, grief, delusion, decay and
> death is your innermost Self. Knowing this very Self the Brāhmaṇas
> **renounce the desire for sons, for wealth and for the worlds**, and lead a mendicant life.(Brihadaranyaka Up 3.5.1)